# The subscription can't have the first charge for free. ErrorCode: DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am using RevenueCat for in-app purchases in my app. I am using this code for upgrading the subscription:

```
private fun upgradePackage(packageToBuy: Package, upgradeInfo: UpgradeInfo) {
        Purchases.sharedInstance.purchasePackageWith(
            requireActivity(),
            packageToBuy,
            upgradeInfo,
            onError = { error, _ ->
                viewModel.onUpgradeError(error)
            },
            onSuccess = { _, purchaserInfo ->
                viewModel.onUpgradeSuccess(purchaserInfo)
            })
    }
```

It was working fine but recently I am getting an error:

> E/[Purchases] - ERROR: ‼️ BillingWrapper purchases failed to update: DebugMessage: The subscription can't have the first charge for free.. ErrorCode: DEVELOPER_ERROR.null
> E/[Purchases] - ERROR: ‼️ One or more of the arguments provided are invalid.

As per billing client documentation, we get DEVELOPER_ERROR when:

> Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate
> that the application was not correctly signed or properly set up for
> In-app Billing in Google Play, or does not have the necessary
> permissions in its manifest.

What does this error message "The subscription can't have the first charge for free." imply? The method used to work before, just stopped working recently. Even the old tested version of my app stopped working now. I've tested in 3.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0 versions of RevenueCat.

Answer (score 1):

As per the revenue cat support reply, the issue is occurring due to google suspending free trials in India.

Comment: can you give any refrence?

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/indias-new-subscription-rules This is a blog from revenuecat regarding India changes. Although they didn't mention specifically about changing subscription plan, but I think its fairly obvious that the new rules will affect plan change too (since there will be no billing cycle anymore).

Comment: in my case, it happened when I change the date to future date and got fixed after setting date.